# Can I have a while loop to iterate within an AJAX success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm attempting to dynamically create an accordion and populate the content of each tab dynamically by AJAX, my main HTML page has an empty div for the accordion

```
<div id="accordion"></div>
```

if the end goal is to have the div populate for returned data from the server and look like so:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <p> accordion tab title 1</p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>jon</li>
            <li>jill</li>
            <li>jacob</li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <p>accordion tab title 2</p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>ben</li>
            <li>brittany</li>
            <li>bob</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>accordion tab title 3</p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>larry</li>
            <li>laura</li>
            <li>lilly</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would I be able to use a while loop inside of my AJAX success function to iterate through the data and create the list items? Here's the function I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    var $accordion= $("#accordion");
    $.ajax({

        type:'GET',
        url: "PDOconnect.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i,data){

            $accordion.append('<p>'+ data.title + '</p>');
            $accordion.append('<div><ul></ul></div>');
            );
        })
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }
    });// end ajax 
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It seems like it would work. Do you have any errors?

Comment: yes..why not.. though seems extra `);` after `$accordion.append('<div><ul></ul></div>');` line

Comment: The success function is just like any other function. jQuery doesn't care what you are doing inside the function.

Comment: What is your issue? Why are you talking about `while` loop? I mean i don't see any purpose for a `while` loop here

Answer (score 0):

The success callback for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) runs after the ajax call has been successfully completed. This means you can manipulate the data however you like inside it in a number of different ways.

Mapping, filtering, reducing, and simple looping are some common ways in which front-end engineers might go about using the data from the server on the webpage.

You can put loops in here just fine, and in fact that's how most people load data into lists.